# Rails REST API POST params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I'm building a RESTful (or mostly RESTful...) API using Rails and have a simple question that I have been strugging to find an answer to.

Essentially it seems like Rails convention is to wrap attributes inside the name of a resource on POST and PUT calls. What I mean is usually you create or update an object in the following manner inside a controller:

```
Object.create(params[:object])
```

or

```
Object.update_attributes(params[:object])
```

My question is; is there a reason for this? If I have a simple class, say a Comment class, that has only a content attribute, I could have the following

```
Comment.create(content: params[:content])
```

Is there a Rails/Rubyist/API reason why the above is not recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails form helpers usually wrap object attributes in an array named from the object and available in the params.

You can decide to format your params differently, that's up to yo, just avoid naming collisions.

As for: `Comment.create(params[:content])`
 will not work.

Do:

```
Comment.create(content: params[:content])
```